# Why does Blur effect of 0 causes Status Bar to collapse in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, blur

**Context**

I have a `ViewModifier` that is blurring the screen when `scenePhase` is `.inactive` and lockes the app when it is`.background`.

This works great despite one major bug: Every time the app goes from `.inactive` where the screen is blurred back to `.active`, the status bar collapses with the screen content moving up inside it. See the image below.

> **Note:** When changing the blur for the `.active` state from 0 to 0.00001, everything works fine.

[image: Screen content going into status bar]

---

**Code**

```swift
struct AppLockViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @ObservedObject private var appLockVM = AppLockViewModel.shared
    @State private var blurRadius: CGFloat = 16
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if appLockVM.locked {
                AppLockView()
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
        .blur(radius: blurRadius)
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in updateBlurRadius(newValue) }
    }
    
    private func updateBlurRadius(_ scenePhase: ScenePhase) {
        switch scenePhase {
        case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
        case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 16 }
        case .background: appLockVM.locked = true
        @unknown default: print("Unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- What is causing this bug and how can I solve it?

Comment: "When changing the blur for the .active state from 0 to 0.00001, everything works fine." So, problem solved.

Comment: @matt this works obviously however it is a bit hacky solution and I would also like to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Have you tested on a real device? The simulator has many layout bugs that real devices don't.

Comment: @robmayoff yes, still happens on a real device :/